# How to test for dependencies on the compiling puppet node

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to test, in a puppet manifest, for a dependency on the **compiling** node (the master or the applying node in case of a masterless setup)?

I've written a profile manifest for base nodes in my network. All nodes should include this profile, including the puppet masters. In this profile, some parts use puppetdb. This gets installed via a puppetmaster profile manifest. I need a way to conditionally skip the parts of the base profile manifest that uses puppetdb, until it is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes We Can :-)

I think your question alludes to the fact that Facter only gathers information about the `agent` node, rather than the `master`.

To retrieve state from the `master`, you can use the [generate](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/function.html#generate) function like this:

```
if generate('/usr/local/bin/is-puppetdb-installed') =~ /^yes/ {
    $puppetdb_installed = true
}
```

You will need to write a generator script that produces appropriate output.